# Implementing a linkedlist in java

Tags: java, linked-list

I am learning data structures current and below is my implementation for linkedlist.I have kept it as simple as possible as my aim here is to understand the logic.

```
/*
 * Singly linked list
 */
package linkedlisttest;


class Node {
    int data;
    Node next;

    public Node(int data) 
    {
        this.data = data;
    }

}

class LinkedList {

    Node head;

    public void add(int data) 
    {
        if (head == null) 
        {
            head = new Node(data);  
            return;
        }

        Node current = head;
        while (current.next != null) {
            current = current.next;
        }
        current.next = new Node(data);
    }

    public int getSize() {
        int i = 0;
        Node current = head;
        while (current != null) {
            i += 1;
            current = current.next;
        }
        return i;
    }

    public void add(int data, int index) 
    {
        if (head == null && index == 0) 
        {
              head = new Node(data);
              return;
        } else if (head == null && index != 0) {
              return; // invalid position
        } else if ( index > getSize() ) {
            return;
        }

        Node current = head;
        //iterate through whole list 
        int pos = -1; 
        Node previous = null;
        Node next = null;
        Node newNode = new Node(data);
        //find next and previous nodes with relation to position
        while (current != null) {
            if (pos == index - 1) {
                previous = current;
            } else if (pos == index + 1) {
                next = current;
            }
            pos++;
            current = current.next;
        }
        previous.next = newNode;

        newNode.next = next;

    }

    public void print() 
    {
        Node current = head;
        while (current.next != null) {
            System.out.print(current.data + "->");
            current = current.next;
        }
        System.out.print(current.data);
    }

}

public class LinkedListTest {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList lt = new LinkedList();
        lt.add(3);
        lt.add(5);
        lt.add(6);
        lt.add(4,1);
        lt.print();
    }

}
```

The bug happens for `lt.add(4,1)` and i suspect its an off by one error.

Expected output: `3->4->6`

Actual output: `3->5->4`

Thanks for the help guys...

**Edit**

Thanks to **@StephenP** and **@rosemilk** for their help.Indeed the code above has a logical bug as it replaces the value at index and not add it.

Here is the new optimized code

```
/*
 * Singly linked list
 */
package linkedlisttest;

class Node {

    int data;
    Node next;

    public Node(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}

class LinkedList {

    Node head;
    int size;

    /**
     *
     * @param data element to add to list 
     * Time Complexity : O(n)
     */
    public void add(int data) {
        if (head == null) {
            head = new Node(data);
            size += 1;
            return;
        }

        Node current = head;
        while (current.next != null) {
            current = current.next;
        }
        current.next = new Node(data);
        size += 1;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return size of list 
     * Time Complexity: O(1) 
     * This is because we use a class
     * variable size to keep track of size of linked list
     */
    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }
    /**
     * 
     * @param data element to insert 
     * @param index position at which to insert the element (zero based)
     * Time Complexity : O(n)
     */
    public void add(int data, int index) {

        if (index > getSize()) {
            return; // invalid position
        }

        Node current = head; //iterate through whole list 
        int pos = 0;
        Node newNode = new Node(data);

        if (index == 0) // special case, since its a single reference change!
        {
            newNode.next = head;
            head = newNode; // this node is now the head
            size += 1;
            return;
        }
        while (current.next != null) {
            if (pos == index - 1) {
                break;
            }
            pos++;
            current = current.next;
        }
        // These are 2 reference changes, as compared to adding at index 0
        newNode.next = current.next; // here we are changing a refernce
        current.next = newNode; // changing a reference here as well
        size += 1;

    }

    /**
     * Prints the whole linked list 
     * Time Complexity : O(n)
     */
    public void print() {

        if(getSize() == 0) { //list is empty
            return;
        }
        Node current = head;
        while (current.next != null) {
            System.out.print(current.data + "->");
            current = current.next;
        }
        System.out.print(current.data + "\n"); 
    }
}

public class LinkedListTest {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList lt = new LinkedList();
        lt.print();
        lt.add(3);
        lt.add(5);
        lt.add(6);
        lt.print();
        lt.add(4, 1);
        lt.print();
        lt.add(4, 7);// 7 is an invalid index
        lt.add(8, 3);
        lt.print();
    }

}
```

Comment: Go through your add method with pen and paper and mark down expected vs actual for each variable at each line

Comment: Shouldn't the expected output be `3->4->5->6`? `add(n,i)` should _add_ the value n at position i, not _replace_ the current value at position i

Comment: When you've figured out and understand why your `add(int, int)` method isn't working as you want, afterward consider (as an exercise because you're learning) how/if you could improve your design if your `class LinkedList` had members `Node head; Node tail; int size;` that it maintained when adding & removing nodes.

Comment: @Stephen P you are right ....i did a design mistake.This method should be called `replace`

Comment: @StephenP if i use a node for the `tail`. it will make it a doubly linked list.I am trying to keep it a singly linked list

Comment: @user2650277 no, it won't make it doubly linked. For doubly linked your `Node` would have to have both a `Node next;` and a `Node prev;` ... In the case I'm talking about, the `LinkedList` class would have a `Node head;` and a `Node tail;` -- keeping track of the tail node makes it fast to append to the list `O(1)`; without that you would have to start at the head and traverse the whole list to append a new node `O(n)`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `add (int , int )` function has a logical bug and can be made better. You don't need previous current and next references, and can cleverly manipulate the list using just the reference to current node, handling inseration at index 0 separately. I would write the `add` function as follows

```
public void add(int data, int index) 
{
    if ( index > getSize() ) {
        return; // invalid position
    }

    Node current = head; //iterate through whole list 
    int pos = 0; 
    Node newNode = new Node(data);

    if (index == 0) // special case, since its a single reference change!
    {
        newNode.next = head; 
        head = newNode; // this node is now the head
        return;
    }
    while (current.next != null) {
        if (pos == index - 1) {
            break;
        }
        pos++;
        current = current.next;
    }
    // These are 2 reference changes, as compared to adding at index 0
    newNode.next = current.next; // here we are changing a refernce
    current.next = newNode; // changing a reference here as well

}
```

Also, your `print` function gives a `NullPointerException` when you try to print an empty list. I would write the print function like this,

```
public void print() 
{
    Node current = head;
    while (current != null) {
        System.out.print(current.data + "->");
        current = current.next;
    }
    System.out.println("null"); // this is just to say last node next points to null!
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Nice code, and inserts as I proposed (`3->4->5->6`) and is O(n) where the OP's is O(n^2) because it calls `getSize()` which itself has to traverse the entire list.

Comment: @StephenP and rosemilk thanks a lot for your help.Check the edit and let me know what you think

Answer (score 0):

Currently, if you print out `pos` in your loop, the indices are -1, 0, 1 (instead of 0, 1, 2), so it'll never "find" the correct `next`. Replace `int pos = -1;` with `int pos = 0;` and it'll work.

I do agree with @StephenP that the output should (arguably) be `3->4->5->6`, but that's a design decision.